# Lemma 3.9 Rudin's functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I need help in understanding the proof of the following

> Suppose $\Lambda_1,\ldots,\Lambda_n$ and $\Lambda$ are linear
>   functionals on a vector space $X$. Let 
>   $$ N = \left\{x : \Lambda_1x =
>  \ldots = \Lambda_n = 0 \right\} $$ The following three are equivalent
>
> a) There are scalars $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ such that 
>   $$ \Lambda =
>  \alpha_1 \Lambda_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n \Lambda_n $$
>
> b) There's $\gamma < \infty$ such that $$ |\Lambda x | \leq \gamma
> > \max_{1\leq i \leq n} |\Lambda_i x| \;\;,(x\in X) $$
>
> c) $\Lambda x = 0$ for every $x \in N$.

Proof: It is clear that (a) implies (b) and that (b) implies (c)...etc.

That's the bit I don't get. How does (a) implies (b)? I believe I get why (b) implies (c). Since if $x \in N$ then for each $i$ we have $\Lambda_i x = 0$, but then by (b) we have $|\Lambda x = 0|$ and this implies $\Lambda x = 0$. (correct?)

So again

Why (a) implies (b)? Is my proof of (b) implies (c) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of (b) implies (c) is correct.

As for (a) implies (b):

We have
$$
| \Lambda x |
= | \alpha_1\Lambda_1 x +\dots + \alpha_n\Lambda_n x | 
\\
\leq | \alpha_1|\cdot |\Lambda_1 x | +\dots + |\alpha_n|\cdot |\Lambda_n x|
\\
\leq  (|\alpha_1|+\dots + |\alpha_n|) \max_{1\leq i \leq n} |\Lambda_i x|.
$$
This means we can choose
$\gamma=|\alpha_1|+\dots + |\alpha_n|$.

Answer (score 1):

a) implies b): $|\Lambda x| \leq \sum |\alpha_i| | \Lambda_i x|\leq \max\{|\Lambda_i(x)|\} \sum |\alpha_i|$ so you can take $\gamma =\sum |\alpha_i|$ Your argument for b) implies c) is correct.